# Create a launcher for a node.js script

Tags: bash, node.js

I'm trying to create a launcher for node.js scripts (so that I can run the scripts by clicking on their file icons instead of launching them from the terminal.) How is this usually done? I'd prefer if I could simply run a script in the terminal by clicking on its icon.

I tried writing a shell script to launch another script in the same folder, but it doesn't show the node.js script's command line output for some reason:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter a node.js script to run > "
read text
node "$text"
```

Comment: Is this Windows or Gnome or KDE or ...???

Comment: It's actually (Ubuntu) Linux.

Comment: This post looks relevant, but it doesn't appear to be an exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806571/is-it-possible-to-run-node-js-scripts-without-invoking-node

Comment: I found something that appears to be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806571/is-it-possible-to-run-node-js-scripts-without-invoking-node

Comment: The linked post describes making your JS files executable _themselves_, by adding a shebang line (`!#…`) and applying `chmod +x`. If your JS files are only invoked from a a shell, that's a convenient option. Opening such files in a GUI file manager, however, will typically not give you what you want; for instance, Finder in OS X runs the script in a visible Terminal window, but exits the shell too once the script has finished running, leaving the window read-only. On Ubuntu, opening an executable script from Files, the file manager,  opens it for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use this to start my node scripts on debian in the terminal

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
dir=$(dirname $0)
script="$dir/path_to_your_server.js"
echo "node $script"
```

Comment: Where should the .sh script and the .js script be located, respectively?

Comment: "path_to_your_server.js" would be the relative path to the file, where $dir is the directory where the .sh file is located

for example my .sh script is located in /bin and my server.js is located in / of my project dir, so it would be script="$dir/../server.js"

Comment: Is it possible to change the script so that the terminal stays open even after the script is finished running?

Answer (score 4):

I now know that you're looking for an Ubuntu solution, but in case someone is interested in an **OS X** solution, here goes:

- Open Automator.
- Create a new application.
- Add an AppleScript action
- Paste the following code:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Terminal"
        repeat with f in input
            do script "node " & quoted form of (POSIX path of f)
        end repeat
        activate
    end tell

end run
```

- Save the application.
- In Finder, control-click any *.js file and select Open With > Other ..., pick the new application and check 'Always Open With.'

From then on, whenever you open a *.js file, it will open in a *new* Terminal window that will *stay open* after node finishes running; add `; exit` to the command string above to close automatically (possibly adding `read -sn 1` first to wait for a keystroke first.)

Comment: Is it possible to do the equivalent using sh? I'm trying to find a solution that will work on most (or perhaps all) Unix-like operating systems.

Comment: While I don't see any technical problem with the script in your question (it should output whatever `node` outputs), I don't see an advantage over simply calling `node` _directly_ with the *.js file as the argument. As to the larger question of changing what the various GUI file managers do when opening a *.js, I suspect there is no generic answer. There's a generic _Ubuntu_ answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4361/how-are-file-extensions-mime-types-icons-default-applications-asssociated?rq=1), but you'll have to figure out how to specify a shell command/script as an application.