# Run a node.js server from Geany

Tags: node.js, geany

A simple question: Is it possible to configure the Geany IDE so that Node.js servers can be run directly from Geany using the "Run" button?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When inside a JS file, go to `Build > Set Build Commands`, there should be a section title `Execute commands`. To use `node` to execute your files, put: `node "%f"` in the "Execute" command textbox.

When you change this, any `.js` files you are editing will run node in the virtual terminal when you hit `F5`.

If you want to set up an entire project to run the server whenever you're working somewhere within a given directory structure, you'll have to mess with project-level configuration. (something I don't usually bother with) My solution here just gives you a quick way to execute a single JS file without using an external terminal.

UPDATE: `node "%f"` seems to be legacy, but `nodejs "%f"` works