# tcsh on Windows: hashbang file support

Tags: windows, tcsh, shebang

I'm using pre-build binary exe of tcsh on Windows.

I'm trying to write some clojure script. like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env java clojure.main

(prn "Hello World!\n")
```

first I try to direct run it in tcsh:

```
# cat test
#!/usr/bin/env java clojure.main

(prn "Hello World\n")
# ./test
#
```

no lucky: a "choose correct program to open this file" window occurs, but not execute it.

I'm trying to add +x mod to it:

```
# chmod +x test
# ls-F -l test
-rwxr-xr-x    1 SW       Administ       59 Oct  9 01:25 test*
# ./test
```

still the same :(

the question is:

- Does the pre-build version of tcsh on Windows support hashbang?
- If so, how to make it execute the file with hashbang?

Thx for a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest instead compiling your program as an uberjar? A jar can be executed by name just as you would your wrapper script, but this way you don't need the extra wrapper.

Download the latest version of leiningen and create a project `$ lein new foo` and then go into the directory. When you are in the process of developing your code you'll probably want to use a repl (`$ lein repl`), or call `$ lein run` to run it from the command line.

Edit src/foo/core.clj: add a gen-class for AOT compilation, and a main function.

```
(ns foo.core
  (:gen-class))
```

```
(defn -main [& [a]]
  (println (format "Hello, %s World!" a)))
```

Edit project.clj and make this the main class:

```
(defproject foo "0.0.1"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]]
  :main foo.core)
```

Now compile the uberjar and make it executable:

`$ lein do clean, compile, uberjar ; chmod +x ./target/foo-0.0.1-standalone.jar`

The executable jar is in the target/ directory, which you can now call by name like any other executable:

```
$ cd target
$ mv foo-0.0.1-standalone.jar foo
$ ./foo crazy
Hello, crazy World!
$ ./foo
Hello, null World!
```

### Other Approaches

#### Leiningen w/ shebang

Use leiningen shebang-style http://charsequence.blogspot.com/2012/04/scripting-clojure-with-leiningen-2.html

#### ClojureScript + V8 -> js w/ shebang

Clojure is not really the best choice for command-line scripting, because of JVM warm up time. ClojureScript + V8 engine was put forward (at the inaugural announcement of ClojureScript by Rich Hickey) as a better solution for scripting. Here is blog article with a detailed example http://mmcgrana.github.com/2011/09/clojurescript-nodejs.html And here is a StackOverflow answer showing how to use node in a shebang: [Is it possible to run Node.js scripts without invoking `node`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806571/is-it-possible-to-run-node-js-scripts-without-invoking-node)

However since your goal seems to be to have no compile step, you may want to write a script that you will use in your shebang that builds the js from cljs before running it.  In this case, you will again have the same JVM start-up time issue, so you may be better off with Debasish's simpler approach linked above.

Comment: But a jar can not modify easily. My original idea is using clojure as a script language, such as using its source code as a single executable file. but thank you all the same as to create a clojure project and to compile it to jar is another subject I want to know. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to this party :-).

To answer the direct questions about hashbang support on Windows: the prebuilt tcsh on Widows has a `TCSHSUBSTHB` environment variable that can be set. From the README.NT it is described as:

> Specifies mappings for hashbang emulation. Should be ';'-separated
>   pairs of blank-separated mappings. 
>       For example,
>
> ```
>    setenv TCSHSUBSTHB "/usr/local/bin/perl c:/bin/perl.exe;"
> ```
>
> will substitute `#!c:/bin/perl.exe` for scripts which have `#!/usr/local/bin/perl` at the top.
>
> The final ';' MUST be included.

For example in my .tcshc I have

> ```
> setenv TCSHSUBSTHB "/usr/bin/tclsh j:/Tcl/bin/tclsh84.exe;"
> ```

If you can get away with putting `#!/usr/bin/java` at the top of this script then you can use `TCSHSUBSTHB` to map to your Windows `java.exe`.

Another way to work around this is to use Cygwin's tcsh, which, being more Unix like, supports hashbang.