# How to run a node.js app from name

Tags: node.js

How do you create a console app that you can run by a name instead of using node and a .js file to start the app?

Instead of...
 $ node myapp.js --out ./folder/

Can I...
 $ myapp --out ./folder/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run Node.js scripts without invoking \`node\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806571/is-it-possible-to-run-node-js-scripts-without-invoking-node). Question info applies to all Unices, not just OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `bin` option in your package.json file to make your script executable. From the documentation for package.json:

> A lot of packages have one or more executable files that they'd like
>   to install into the PATH. npm makes this pretty easy (in fact, it uses
>   this feature to install the "npm" executable.)
>
> To use this, supply a bin field in your package.json which is a map of
>   command name to local file name. On install, npm will symlink that
>   file into prefix/bin for global installs, or ./node_modules/.bin/ for
>   local installs.

Click the link and search for `bin`: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html for more info.

Comment: I suppose this allows to distribute your script. It doesn't help to create it.

Comment: what do you mean? If you specify the `bin` option, you can run npm install and then it will copy it into your PATH

Comment: Do you mean that `npm` will automatically create the file for the `bin` directory?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. It will create a symlink inside `bin`. Refer to that link for more info.