# cannot find node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, couchdb

Im following along with a nodejs book node.js the right way and im stuck when trying to execute this command. I changed #!/usr/bin/env to #!/usr/bin/node because env wasn't even a folder for me and node.js is in the node folder I believe. Im running ubuntu 14.04. Whats the fix? I have couchdb running in the background if that matters. Thanks

```
ryan@Ryan:~/Documents/code/databases$ ./dbcli.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/ryan/Documents/code/databases/node --harmony'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3
```

and heres the program

```
#!/usr/bin/node node --harmony
/***
 * Excerpted from "Node.js the Right Way",
 * published by The Pragmatic Bookshelf.
 * Copyrights apply to this code. It may not be used to create training material, 
 * courses, books, articles, and the like. Contact us if you are in doubt.
 * We make no guarantees that this code is fit for any purpose. 
 * Visit http://www.pragmaticprogrammer.com/titles/jwnode for more book information.
***/
const
  request = require('request'),
  options = {
    method: process.argv[2] || 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:5984/' + (process.argv[3] || '')
  };
request(options, function(err, res, body) {
  if (err) {
    throw Error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(res.statusCode, JSON.parse(body));
  }
});
```

Comment: Posting a small code snippet from `dbcli.js` could help inform an answer, so it might be worth adding in

Comment: What happens when you just type `node -v` at the command prompt?  Does it run node and show you the version?  Is it in your path?

Comment: v0.10.40     Not sure what you mean by path, but yea i have it installed.

Comment: And, last I checked, you can't put `#!/usr/bin/node node --harmony` in a .js file that you pass to node becaus that isn't valid Javascript.  You can remove that line and run the .js file manually by just typing this:   `node --harmony dbcli.js`.

Comment: ill try that! sounds right

Comment: ayyyyyy, we good we good! thanks so much man! yup, simple fix

Comment: so the book screwed up , not me!

Comment: Telling someone wondering why the shebang is not working that the "solution" is not to use it is, well, uhhh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer since it solved your problem:

Last I checked, you can't put `#!/usr/bin/node node --harmony` in a .js file that you pass to node becaus that isn't valid Javascript.  You can remove that line and run the .js file manually by just typing this:

```
node --harmony dbcli.js
```

FYI, it looks like it's possible to do what you were trying to do, but you weren't using the proper syntax since you were trying to run `node node`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806571/is-it-possible-to-run-node-js-scripts-without-invoking-node).

Answer (score 0):

The shebang line should be

```
#!/usr/bin/node --harmony
```

With your current line, you are telling node to run the module called "node".